# jQuery Click vs User Click different behaviour in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

The problem is the following:

I have a UserControl_1 inside a UserControl_2 and UserControl_1 has an event that's is being subscribed by UserControl_2. This event is fired on a Button click in UserControl_1.

When the user manually clicks on this button, all is ok and the event is well routed to the handler in UserControl_2, **BUT** when the click on this button is done through jQuery the event is not routed to UserControl_2.

The problem is that dispite the fact that the button handler in UserControl_1 is being called, when trying to route the event to UserControl_2 the handler is null, as if no control had subscribed it.

The code that routes/bubbles the event in UserControl_1 is the following:

```
public event MyFileUploadCommandEventHandler UploadDone;

protected virtual void OnUploadDone(MyFileUploadCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (UploadDone != null)
            {
                UploadDone(this, e);
            }
        }
```

Here, when called through click in jQuery the UploadDone handler is always null.

My jQuery method i've tested in 2 ways already with the same results:

```
function DoneCallback() {
        $("[id*='btnDoneCallback']").click();
    }
```

and

```
function DoneCallback() {
        __doPostBack('<%=btnDoneCallback.UniqueID%>', '');
    }
```

What is the difference between a user click and a jQuery click event that is causing this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us the jQuery code?

Comment: unless you're doing an ajax call to an exposed web method, the jquery click even is only client side, and doesn't have access to the server side user control.

Comment: i've updated my post with jQuery function code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it by passing the id of the control as a parameter of the javascript function:

```
function DoneCallback(ctl) {
    var id = '#' + ctl;
    $(id).click();
}
```

and have it called like:

```
<div onclick="javascript:DoneCallback('<%=btnDoneCallback.ClientID%>');">CLICK ME!</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the form within the jquery-click-function, then submit it; something like:

```
$(this).parents("form:first").submit();
```

Actually, that's wrong. It's most likely that you'll need to execute JS that asp.net expects to wire the click with appropriate event handler on the server. To generate such JS on the server (for the client to execute), you can use these methods:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()
this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink()
```

They return string (javascript code), which you would need to render to the page, and then call it from your jquery-click when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET triggers a `__doPostBack(eventtarget, eventarguments)` function on click. I am not entirely sure why calling `.click()` on the control does not propagate TBH. But you should probably expose a property in your user controls to expose this function:

```
public string ClientPostbackFunction
{
    get { return ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Button1, "argument", false); }
}
```

Then you can bind that with JQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function() { <%= UserControl1.ClientPostbackFunction %> });
```

Comment: as you can see from my update to the initial post i've already tried using **__doPostBack('<%=btnDoneCallback.UniqueID%>', '');** isn't that the same? Please note that the button handler gets called, the parents event handler is the one that is null.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious...Are you subscribing to the event on all postbacks (opposed to just in !IsPostBack)?